# Sqlite3 связывание временных таблиц по внешнему ключу

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица пользователей, которую нужно хранить на диске. Есть сессии пользователей, которые часто меняются и хочется хранить их в памяти во временной таблице. Создаю таблицы.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY;

CREATE TABLE user (
    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                 NOT NULL,
    name TEXT    NOT NULL,
    pass TEXT    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE session1 (
    id   INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY
                  NOT NULL
                  UNIQUE,
    up   DATETIME NOT NULL
                  DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    down DATETIME,
    user INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Пытаюсь сделать вставку

```
insert into session1(user_id) values(4);
```

Ошибка:

```
[20:08:14] Ошибка при выполнении SQL запроса к базе данных 'test': no such table: temp.user
```

Судя по всему во время вставки в таблицу **session1** интерпритатор считает, что находится в БД **temp**.
Запускаюсь в SQLiteStudio 3.1.1